# (conjunction) 'as' in 'at the same time as when'

Tags: conjunctions

**This happened at the same time as when the window decorations disappeared.**

I don't know the meaning of 'as' in 'at the same time as when' and the usage of 'as' in this situation.

What do you think of four sentences?

```
The first: This happened at the same time as when the window decorations disappeared.

The second:This happened at the same time as the window decorations disappeared.

The third: This happened at the same time as the time the window decorations disappeared. 

The fourth: This happened when the window decorations disappeared.
```

I think the first, the third, and the fourth are right, but the second is wrong.

I wonder how you feel.

Answer (score 1):

*As* is used for comparison and here we compare two times, which are actually the same.

```
This happened at the same time as [the time when] the window decorations disappeared.
```

In your 1st and 3rd sentences the words *when* and *the time* after the conjunction are redundant.
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/at+the+same+time+as

The last sentence has a bit different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Using "as" for "that" is taken by many to be dialectal.

Try:

*This happened at the same time **/that/when/** the window decorations disappeared.*

More informal:

*This happened at the same time the window decorations disappeared.*

Your sentences are too heavy.